# Show that the system has a nontrivial solution.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose that, in a homogeneous linear system, the coefficients of one
> of the unknowns are all equal to zero. Show that the system has a
> nontrivial solution.

**Attempt**: Note that the rank must be less than or equal to the number of columns in the coefficient matrix. If we had all columns of the augmented matrix different from zero, then, after being reduced to row-echelon form, we would have at most rank = number of columns. As we have a null column, then surely the rank is less than the number of columns. Therefore, we will have at least one free variable.

Am I right? Furthermore, is there any way the solution could be more formal than that? (using the same approach)

Comment: Just set the values of all the other unknowns equal to zero. Since the coefficients on the other unknown are all zero any such object will be a solution.